# Parent Version will get overriden by artifact version

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, wicket

Hello Apache Wicket and/or Maven Gurus,

I was trying out an example of Apache Wicket with Springboot from this link:
https://github.com/MarcGiffing/wicket-spring-boot-examples/tree/master/simple

So what I did in the pom.xml is this:

```
...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>1.0.12</version> -->
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.giffing</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <name>simple</name>

  <properties>
    <wicket.version>7.10.0</wicket.version>
  </properties>

...
```

What happens is that it will make the import in HomePage.java:
import com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.context.scan.WicketHomePage;

to be unknown.

*The particular error is:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.context cannot be resolved    HomePage.java /simple/src/main/java/com/giffing/examples/wicket/spring/boot/simple  line 8  Java Problem*

Your expertise will be much appreciated here.

Thanks,
Artanis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there might be some issue with apache-wicket with spring boot example that I have used here. For more information, here is the link:
   https://github.com/MarcGiffing/wicket-spring-boot-examples/issues/2

But this pom.xml worked for my simple apache-wicket with springboot integration project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.artanis</groupId>
  <artifactId>WicketSpringboot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <name>WicketSpringboot</name>
  <description></description>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- maven generated -->
    <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.20.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-install-plugin.version>2.5.2</maven-install-plugin.version>
    <maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.8.2</maven-deploy-plugin.version>

    <!-- Wicket Springboot -->
    <wicket-spring-boot-starter.version>2.1.0</wicket-spring-boot-starter.version>

    <!-- Wicket -->
    <wicket.version>8.0.0-M9</wicket.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Springboot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Wicket Springboot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring-boot-context</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Wicket -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicketstuff-annotation</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j-log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>4.11</version> -->
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <!-- <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/pages</directory>
        </resource> -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <!-- maven generated -->
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-install-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-deploy-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks,
Artanis

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wicket-spring-boot-starter-parent:1.0.10. This is the latest one for Wicket 7.x: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.starter%22%20AND%20a%3A%22wicket-spring-boot-starter-parent%22. 2.x is for Wicket 8.x.

You can use `mvn dependency:tree` in your project to see which versions of Wicket, Spring Boot, Spring are actually resolved.

If this doesn't help then please give more of your pom.xml and more about the error.

Comment: Thanks for your input Martin. I appreciate it. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Somehow it will override the version of wicket-spring-boot-starter-parent to 0.0.1 instead of 1.0.12.

Comment: Please share the complete pom.xml so we can help you more.

Comment: Kindly see my answer below @martin-g. Thanks.